# View Xcode bot logs while bot is running

Tags: xcode-bots

I waste a lot of time when running Xcode bots and I just want to see if I have it configured correctly. My test suite takes 5 minutes to run, so having to wait that amount of time each time I tweak a setting until I can see the results is not ideal. Is there any way I can see the logs as the bot is running?

An alternative approach would be some way to run just a single test, if that's possible. Obviously I could remove/comment all other tests, but I'm looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit tricky to do, but possible.

Xcode Server stores bot log information in `/Library/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/<bot_name_here>/`. 
Within this directory, you will find number folders for each integration (folders named `1/`, `2/`, `3/`, etc), and within each of those folders you will find the following files (not necessarily limited to these but this is what I see):

```
buildService.log
sourceControl.log
trigger-before-0.log
...etc
```

However, this directory is only accessible if you are the root user. If you really want to take a look at logs while bots are running, you can assume root on your server machine with the following command (server password required):

`sudo su -`

then you can navigate to the above directory and observe the log files as they are being written.

Comment: Correct location is `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/<bot_name_here>/` and it does not contain currently running integration's logs. At least not for Xcode 9.1.